# Potential Overflow Comparing Sorts and Comparisons of Various Sorting Algorithms

Tags: c++

Im currently working with a simple program which compares the number of comparisons and swaps for a number of common sorting methods and testing it on data sets of size 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 50000 and 100000. The program appears to be working perfectly up until 50000 values however for example, testing the insertion method with random values at 50000 values yielded a comparison count of 626936785 however at 100000 values the output was -1788822792. I have included the full code below, is there potentially some sort of overflow occuring as the number of swaps and comparisons grows too large to properly keep track of?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
long long comparisons;
long long swaps;

bool comp_less(int a, int b){
    ++comparisons;
    return a < b;
}

void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    ++swaps;
    int t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}

void selectionSort(int *first, int *last)
{

    for(int *i = first; i < (last - 1); ++i){
        int *min = i;
        for(int *j = i + 1; j < last; ++j){
            if(comp_less(*j, *min)){
                min = j;
            }
        }
        swap(*i, *min);
    }

}


void insertionSort(int* first, int* last)
{
    for (int *i = first + 1; i < last; ++i)
    {
        int temp = *i;
        int *j;
        for (j = i; j > first && comp_less(temp, *(j - 1)); --j)
        {
            swap(*j, *(j - 1));
        }
        *j = temp;
    }
}
int *partition(int *first, int *last)
{

    int *pivot = last - 1;
    int *i = first;
    int *j = last - 1;
    for (;;)
    {
        while (comp_less(*i, *pivot) && i < last)
        {
            ++i;
        }
        while (*j >= *pivot && j > first)
        {
            --j;
        }
        if (i >= j)
            break;

        swap(*i, *j);
    }
    swap(*(last - 1), *i);
    return i;
}

void quickSort(int* first, int* last) {
    {
        if ((first - last) <= 1)
            return;
        int *pivot = partition(first, last);

        quickSort(first, pivot);
        quickSort(pivot + 1, last);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string algorithm = "selection";
    string dataset = "random";

    for (int c; (c = getopt(argc, argv, "ravqsin")) != -1;) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'r':
                dataset = "random";
                break;
            case 'a':
                dataset = "sorted";
                break;
            case 'v':
                dataset = "reverse";
                break;
            case 'q':
                algorithm = "quicksort";
                break;
            case 's':
                algorithm = "selection";
                break;
            case 'i':
                algorithm = "insertion";
                break;
            case 'n':
                algorithm = "none";
                break;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    const int size = argc > 0 ? atoi(argv[0]) : 10000;
    int* data = new int[size];

    if (dataset == "sorted") {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] = i;
        }
    }
    else if (dataset == "reverse") {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] = size - i - 1;
        }
    }
    else if (dataset == "random") {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            data[i] = rand() % size;
        }
    }

    if (algorithm == "quicksort") {
        quickSort(data, data + size);
    }
    else if (algorithm == "selection") {
        selectionSort(data, data + size);
    }
    else if (algorithm == "insertion") {
        insertionSort(data, data + size);
    }
    else if (algorithm=="none"){
        cout<< "Oops!" <<'\n';
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "OK" << '\n';
    cout << "Algorithm:   " << algorithm << '\n';
    cout << "Data set:    " << dataset << '\n';
    cout << "Size:        " << size << '\n';
    cout << "Comparisons: " << comparisons << '\n';
    cout << "Swaps:       " << swaps << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which algorithm are you testing?

Comment: Aside: in `partition` you call `comp_less` in the first inner loop but do a direct comparison in the second. Compares will be under-reported for `quicksort`.

Comment: @TonyTannous initially just insertion sort with sorted, reverse sorted and randomly sorted values. The function appears to break at 100000 values for all cases however

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thank you for picking up on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there potentially some sort of overflow occuring as the number of swaps and comparisons grows too large to properly keep track of?

The output seems to indicate that overflow is happening.

You can add a test to be sure.

```
void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    ++swaps;

    if ( swaps == std::numeric_limits<decltype(swaps)>::max() )
    {
        std::cout << "Number of swaps reached max value. Resetting it 0.\n";
        swaps = 0;
    }

    int t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
```

You can change the type of `swaps` to `unsigned long long` to delay the arrival of the maximum value. It's a good practice to stll have that test though.

```
unsigned long long swaps = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, i added your test however it doesn't appear the maximum value is being reached, which makes sense since a long long type shouldn't max out even with 100000 variables.

Comment: Edit: changing the type to unisgned long long appears to have fixed my issue. Why does this delay the maximum value being reached?

Comment: @NicholasFischer, maimum value that an `unsigned long long` can hold is twice the maximum value a `long long` can hold.